# Copy data from one column from database A table A to another database B table B

Tags: oracle

I am trying to copy and replace column C from Database A table A to another Database B table B ...

Please note column C exist in both databases we are trying to replace it.

Database A uses different credentials and database B uses different credentials.

Here is what we are trying to work with ... problem is how we handle connections within the database and how we can replace the column

UPDATE B
SET B.name = (SELECT A.name FROM A WHERE A.id = A.id AND A.name IS NOT NULL)
WHERE B.name IS NULL;

Please let us know

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **database link** to handle connections:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm

```
UPDATE B SET B.name = 
             (SELECT A.name FROM A@link_name 
              WHERE A.id = A.id AND A.name IS NOT NULL) 
WHERE B.name IS NULL;
```